# What is the relationship between WASI and proxy-wasm?

Tags: webassembly, envoyproxy, wasi

[WASI](https://github.com/WebAssembly/WASI) and [proxy-wasm](https://github.com/proxy-wasm/spec) seem to have similar goals - defining an ABI to allow interaction of WASM modules with the host environment (i.e. supporting syscalls), with proxy-wasm focussing on modules that are embedded into proxies.

What's the relationship (current or planned) between the two? I've seen [this](https://github.com/WebAssembly/WASI/commit/6d60cf26ea45689b7bfa0a1aabdd2707399b4372) but not sure what was covered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[proxy-wasm](https://github.com/proxy-wasm/spec) is/was used for the initial development, in order to bootstrap the ecosystem, and to gauge the interest of other vendors in the industry (which was a great success, since others have already created: [AssemblyScript SDK](https://github.com/solo-io/proxy-runtime), [TinyGo SDK](https://github.com/mathetake/proxy-wasm-go), and [WebAssembly Hub](https://webassemblyhub.io/)).

But the idea was always to contribute this ABI to WASI, and we spoke at the WASI meetups on [2019/10/15](https://github.com/WebAssembly/WASI/blob/master/meetings/2019/WASI-10-15.md) and [2020/03/26](https://github.com/WebAssembly/WASI/blob/master/meetings/2020/WASI-03-26.md) about it, so expect the ABI to be incorporated into WASI over the next few weeks/months.